# How to write into an out file the averages of the data in the infile

Tags: python, list, file, loops, file-io

this is my code so far :

```
infileName="data.txt"
inFile=open(infileName,"r")
outfileName="avg.txt"
outFile=open(oufileName,"w")
for line in infile:
    test=line.split()
    first_name=test[0]
    last_name=test[1]
    first_initial=first_name[0]
grades=test[2:]
```

I do not know what to do from here. How do you take the averages from each line?

This is the infile `data.txt`:

```
betty smith 60 100 80 
john williams 50 100 
sue mason 20 30 40 60 50
```

This is supposed to be the outcome on the outfile `avg.txt`:

```
smith,b:80.0 
williams,j:75.0 
mason,s:50.0 –
```

Comment: this is the infile
data.txt"
betty smith 60 100 80
john williams 50 100
#sue mason 20 30 40 60 50

this is supposed to be the outcome on the outfile
avg.txt
smith,b:80.0
williams,j:75.0
mason,s:50.0

Comment: Do you know the formula for computing an average?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You seem to need first to acquire programming basics reading a good book or tutorials. The site cannot provide this kind of help. See [ask].

Comment: Yea, but every person has a different number of tests

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension :

```
>>> [j[1]+','+j[0][0]+':'+str(sum(map(float,j[2:]))//(len(j)-2)) for j in [line.split() for line in open('in_file')]]
['smith,b:80.0', 'williams,j:75.0', 'mason,s:40.0']
```

In this list comprehension first we need to loop over our file and split the lines so we will have the following result  :

```
[line.split() for line in open('in_file')]
[['betty', 'smith', '60', '100', '80'], ['john', 'williams', '50', '100'], ['sue', 'mason', '20', '30', '40', '60', '50']]
```

Now we need to loop over this list, the important part is calculate the avg so first we know that the numbers are from the 2nd index to end so we need to convert this numbers to `float` that it could be done with `map` function then calculate the sum and divide with `len-2`.

```
sum(map(float,j[2:]))//(len(j)-2))
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. but Im confused as to how ur answer is formatted. Meaning where would i implement this

Comment: Is there any chance you could write it like the answers above?

Comment: You could write it in other forms but using list comprehension is more efficient!

Answer (score 1):

Just corrected your code to print the desired result in output file:-

```
def add(a,b): 
    return a+b

infileName="data.txt"
inFile=open(infileName,"r")
outfileName="avg.txt"
outFile=open(outfileName,"w")
for line in inFile.readlines():
    test=line.split()
    first_name=test[0]
    last_name=test[1]
    first_initial=first_name[0]
    no_list = map(float, test[2:])
    avg = float(reduce(add, no_list))/len(no_list)
    outFile.write("%s %s %s\n"%(first_name, last_name, str(avg)))
```

Answer (score 1):

your wanted solution is this...?

```
inFilename = "data.txt"
with open(inFilename, "r") as inFile:
    for line in inFile.readlines():
        test = line.split()
        first_name = test[0]
        last_name = test[1]
        first_initial = first_name[0]
grades = map(float, test[2:])
outfileName = "avg.txt"
with open(outfileName, 'w') as outFile:
    buffer = sum(grades)/len(grades)
    buffer = '{},{}:{}'.format(first_initial, last_name, buffer)
    outFile.write(buffer)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
infileName="data.txt"
inFile=open(infileName,"r")
outfileName="avg.txt"
outFile=open(outfileName,"w")
for content in [line.strip().split(' ') for line in inFile]:
    print '{0}, {1}: {2}'.format(content[1], content[0][0], sum([int(number) for number in content[2:]]) / len(content[2:]))
```

Output:

```
smith, b: 80
williams, j: 75
mason, s: 40
```